# Авто монтирование в ubuntu с помощью Udisks2 а в частности udisksctl

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, mount, rules

Возникла следующая проблема. Присутствие задача которую я решил с помощью udisks2 на с++, я могу отловить сигнал по дебасу если во время работы в машину вставляют флешку. Но отлаживался я на персональной тачке а тула должна крутиться на nano pi. Проблема заключается в том что с помощью udisks2 я могу примонтировать флеху но моя программа не видит сигнала по дебасу в следствии чего не читаются файлы. Веду я к тому что udisks2 на пишке работает но как запустить его что бы он делал это автоматический( при вставлении флехи сам монтировал флеху ). Написал небольшие правила в `/etc/udev/reles.d/99-udisks.rules` где я пытаюсь запустить следующий скрипт:

```
#!/bin/bash

touch /home/pi/aaa

/usr/bin/udisksctl mount -b /dev/sda1 --no-user-interaction
```

Сам файл вот :

```
ENV {ID_FS_USAGE} ==   filesystem|other|crypto  , ENV {UDISKS_FILESYSTEM_SHARED} =   1

ACTION=="add", KERNEL=="sd[a-z][0-9]", RUN+="/home/pi/mo.sh %k"  OPTIONS="last_rule"
ACTION=="remove", RUN+="/home/pi/mu.sh" OPTIONS="last_rule"
```

aaa создается когда втыкаю флеху а вот диск не монтируется. Если запустить скрипт руками то так же смонитировано не чего не будет а если от прав супер пользователя то все получиться и диск примонтируется. Я Уверен что кто то все же сможет мне помочь с данным вопросом.

Comment: так же происходит монтирование при первом запуске пишик и вставление флешки

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если кому то это поможет , для того что бы на старом линуксе происходило авто монтирование и отмонтирование необходимо:

1) Установить зависимость udiskie

2) Положить файл udiskie.service в папку /etc/systemd/system
Сам файл:

```
[Unit]
Description=udiskie automount service

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/udiskie -a -2

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

3) Выполнить команду `systemctl enable udiskie`